# discord.py how to make the bot send a message at a specific time to execute a command

Tags: discord.py

I would like my bot to send a message at a specific time every day running another bot's command.
For example, I want my bot to write "s!t" on a specific channel every day at 2 am and have the message that the bot sends get deleted.
How could I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py Bot send messages at certain times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70995386/discord-py-bot-send-messages-at-certain-times)

Comment: my question was answered years ago.

Comment: That's just an automated message when someone flags your question as a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `APScheduler` and `Cron` to schedule your messages to be sent at a specific time, like 12:00 AM

Docs: [`APScheduler`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [`Cron`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/cron.html)

Here is an example:

```py
#async scheduler so it does not block other events
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

async def func():
    c = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    await c.send("s!t")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

    #initializing scheduler
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    #sends "s!t" to the channel when time hits 10/20/30/40/50/60 seconds, like 12:04:20 PM
    scheduler.add_job(func, CronTrigger(second="0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50")) 

    #starting the scheduler
    scheduler.start()
```

Comment: i can't figure out how to configure 02.00 with scheduler.add_job.

Comment: hour="2", minute="0", second="0"

Comment: I tried to use a close time to see if it worked (like 19.28) but I don't like it and I don't understand why

Comment: [code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/743904389592383488/unknown.png)

Comment: ok works but does not execute the command.I think then it is not possible to execute commands by having the bot write commands.