# At a certain time the Bot writes something in Discord chat with background task

Tags: python, datetime, asynchronous, discord.py, python-asyncio

I wanted to make the Bot greet in the chat at a certain time (like 10:00). The problem is that the "while" is not an asynchronous process (like "asyncio.sleep"). Could somebody tell me how I could do it?

I tried this (writed after "on_ready"):

```
while cyclebb == 1: #"cyclebb" is an always active variable
    blt = f"{datetime.now().hour} : {datetime.now().minute} : {datetime.now().second}"
    if blt == '10 : 42 : 15':
        chn = client.get_channel(964837651108732979)
        await chn.send('Hi guys!!')
        await asyncio.sleep(2) #I put it to prevent spamming
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py Bot send messages at certain times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70995386/discord-py-bot-send-messages-at-certain-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tasks loops. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop

it would look something like so.

```
from discord.ext import tasks

async def on_ready():
     greet_task.start()
     

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def greet_task():
     ...stuff here
```